# error while executing

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the difference between `2` and `'2'` in Oracle?

Different datatype ?

```
select 1 from tab union select '2' from tab;
```

error occurred

Comment: Yes, different data types

Answer (score 3):

Yes, different data types; `2` is an integer, where `'2'` is a string literal, so they are in different data types, thats why you are getting an error.

When you use `UNION` the data types should be matching; they should be either integer or string literals like this:

```
select 1 from tab union select 2 from tab;
```

Comment: Intriguiingly, Oracle documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i139891) is inconsistent on whether the literal `1` is a number or integer.  The documentation has examples of both for strings of digits with no decimal point.  (This detail doesn't really change the answer.)

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Aha, thanks for the note. I am not aware of Oracle terminology.

Comment: Bit odd that it distinguishes at all here as integer isn't really a seperate type. The bit about using text literals is even stranger as it's recommending implicit conversion. Even if the NLS setting has comma as the decimal seperator a number literal still always uses a period.

Answer (score 0):

bit more info to @Mahmoud Gamal answer
see the simple test

```
create table t1 as select 1 as col1 from dual;
create table t2 as select '1' as col1 from dual;
```

and then in SQL Plus we can see that t1.col1 is numeric, but t2.col1 is CHAR(1)

```
Connected to Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 
Connected as ***

SQL> desc t1;
Name Type   Nullable Default Comments 
---- ------ -------- ------- -------- 
COL1 NUMBER Y                         

SQL> desc t2;
Name Type    Nullable Default Comments 
---- ------- -------- ------- -------- 
COL1 CHAR(1) Y                         

SQL>
```